# What diagrams can be used to visualize 4-dimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays

How can I understand visualize a 4 dimension array in my head?

1 dimension is pretty easy: x x x x x x

2 dimension I still have no problems:

```
x x x x x x 
x x x x x x 
x x x x x x
```

3 dimensions, I can not draw here but I can imagine more x 's coming out from each x in the 2 dimension array.

How about 4 dimension?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a programming related question.  However: if 3 dimensions looks like a cube of Xs, 4 might look like a cube of 1-dimensional-arrays.

Comment: That's trivial, just start with visualising 4 orthonormal vectors.

Comment: It depends on the application - it could be (as already suggested) a cube of 1D arrays, or it could be a 1D array of cubes, or a time-dependent sequence of cubes, or even a 2D array of 2D arrays... It really depends on your problem domain...

Comment: You can never visualize anything other than 3d. When you say you can visualize a 2d world, you are really seeing a 2d surface embedded in three dimentions. And same for 1d. As for 4d, forget it.

Comment: @Iowa15, our brains are not equipped to visualize a 4-D physical object, but a finite amount of 4-dimensional _data_ can be "flattened" to fit in a 3-D or a 2-D space (e.g., see twalberg's comment).

Answer (score 2):

For 4D, You would imagine having another dimension, where there is a 3D cube at each point along that dimension. Similarly for more dimensions.

Think about how 4d arrays work in Java, or C - in both cases they are just arrays of arrays of arrays. You can also visualize them like that.

But in many cases, a 4D-array will be used like a cache, like array[iteration][object_id][g-force][whatever] . Thre is no point in visualizing that.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an array for each 'x' in your array, you can begin to simulate multidimensional arrays.  Like this:

```
[[x,x],[x,x,x]], [[x,x,x],[x,x]]
[[x,x],[x,x,x]], [[x,x,x],[x,x]]
```

A four dimensional array is just a 2d array of 2d arrays. Or, an array of arrays of arrays of arrays.